# what is the meaning of "engage in an argument"

Tags: meaning

Imagine that, a guy and I are discussing something, they reply

> If you want to engage in an argument ...

What does that mean? I guess I could consider "argument" as "fight with words". Does "engage in an argument" mean "challenge"?

Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you endeavour to find out yourself, perhaps by looking on the 'Net or in a dictionary?

Comment: @BillJ ... Nuance or vernacular subtlety can be most confusing for students learning a new language...be kind.

Comment: @Katherine SE expects learners to demonstrate that they have done some research before submitting a question, and to include what they think the answer is. Incidentally, thanks for the advice, but I'm well aware of the issues facing learners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb "engage" has several meanings.  Of these, two seem relevant to your question:

> **Engage**:  1. to interest someone in something and keep them thinking about it;
>
> 2. to attack or begin to fight someone (usually refers to military action)

In this query, the suggestion of "challenge" is more appropriate than "fight" for a war of words.  It all depends on context.  If the argument may result in bodily harm, then maybe "fight" is appropriate.  However, if the argument is more of a debate, then the "challenge" is about thinking and interest in the topic being argued.